# How can I get all the files inside `/var` and its subdirectories and ignore listing out folder name?

Tags: ruby, file

How can I get all the files inside `/var` and its subdirectories but at the same time, ignoring list out subdirectory folder name?

I have tried `Dir["/var/*"]` but it doesn't list all the files inside sub directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dir["/var/**/*"]
```

The `**` that appears in this pattern matches any path fragment of zero or more nested directories, but doesn't match files.

Let's break that down:

When you have `/var/somefile.txt` (which likely doesn't exist on your system, because `/var` most likely only has directories in it), here's what each part of your glob would match:

```
Part of pattern     Part of directory path
     /var                 /var
     **                   (nothing)
     *                    somefile.txt
```

For the file `/var/run/NetworkManager.pid`:

```
Part of pattern     Part of directory path
     /var                 /var
     **                   run
     *                    NetworkManager.pid
```

For the file `/var/spool/mail/news`:

```
Part of pattern     Part of directory path
     /var                 /var
     **                   spool/mail
     *                    news
```

I'm not sure what `Dir['/var/**']` on its own does. I think that to make it work the way you expect, you always need another path component after the `**`.

Comment: Could you explain what is fragemnt of zero, and what files doesn't matched?

Comment: @KitHo "Path fragment of zero…nested directories" would be any file in `/var`. Also I'm not sure what is meant by "doesn't match any files", because it most certainly does.